# Applying css styling for native material select

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, angular-material

I have two dropdown below:

1. Basic Mat select
2. Basic native select

> ```
> <h4>Basic mat-select</h4>
> <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
>   <mat-label>Favorite food</mat-label>
>   <mat-select>
>     <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value">
>       {{food.viewValue}}
>     </mat-option>
>   </mat-select>
> </mat-form-field>
>
> <h4>Basic native select</h4>
> <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
>   <mat-label>Cars</mat-label>
>   <select matNativeControl required>
>     <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
>     <option value="saab">Saab</option>
>     <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
>     <option value="audi">Audi</option>
>   </select>
> </mat-form-field>
> ```

I need to use 2nd one, Basic native select and apply css styling which looks similar to 1st one. I dont want exact same but somewhat similar, is it possible?

refer this code https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview

[image]

Comment: Do you mean you want the drop down to look the same? @SmartestVEGA

Comment: Also what's the issue in using the basic mat-select?

Comment: yes, in micro front environment basic mat select are not selecting, it froze the list of dropdowns and cant select, hence i using basic native mat select

Comment: From what I know and have experienced there's no simple way to do it using just css. You will also need JS. You will have to do something like this https://codepen.io/wallaceerick/pen/nJLPvN

Comment: Also see if there two links help:
1. https://moderncss.dev/custom-select-styles-with-pure-css/
2. https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/css/how-to-style-a-select-box-drop-down-with-only-css.html

Comment: Thanks, can u post it answer i will accept

Comment: Cool will do! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I know and have experienced there's no simple way to do it using just CSS. You will also need JS.

These two links should help:

1. [https://moderncss.dev/custom-select-styles-with-pure-css/][2]
2. [https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/css/how-to-style-a-select-box-drop-down-with-only-css.html][3]
3. Additionally you can checkout more examples on codepen.io